# Regarding rosdep

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each new time we start ROS do we need to run sudo rosdep install command every time or we can simply use rosdep update

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275967/regarding-rosdep/) by [ujas mandavia](https://answers.ros.org/users/32636/ujas-mandavia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdep install` sets up some files that rosdep isn't able to install when you install rosdep. You only need to do this once, **when you install rosdep**.

`rosdep update` updates the dependency database for resolving generic system package names to packages for your operating system.

The only times when you need to do this are during the initial installation (to initialize the database), and before you run `rosdep install`, to make sure that you have the most recent database before installing system packages.

The rosdep database doesn't change often, so running `rosdep update` more than once a day probably won't help unless you know that there has been a database change since the last time you ran it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1